# ZeroMQ securely over the internet

Tags: ruby, sockets, ssl, zeromq

I've been working with zeroMQ a bit and I want to be able to connect securely over the Internet. I'm in ruby and could use SSL and/or some sort of shh connection but cannot find any examples of how to do this.

I found this old stackoverflow link, [How does zeromq work together with SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391435/how-does-zeromq-work-together-with-ssl) saying they were working on some sort of security, but that was a year ago and I can't find any new references.

Even if this isn't built into zeroMQ, I would assume that there would be some way to set this up with OpenSSL or something similar.

Note: zeroMQ website mentions using VPN or something if you want secure transport. I do not want to use VPN. There must be a better way.

Comment: How about tunneling through SSH?

Comment: http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: Ya, ssh tunnel will work and seems pretty straight forward. Just thought there might be a better, more standard way to do this with zeroMQ

Answer (score 5):

Similar to VPN, but much easier to setup:

- encrypted tunnel with `socat`

Let's make each zeromq side connected locally to `socat`, and two `socat`s connect with each other using encrypted channel.

Some links: [[1]](http://www.blackbytes.info/2012/07/socat-cheatsheet/), [[2]](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssltunnel.html), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391435/how-does-zeromq-work-together-with-ssl), [[4]](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add that since the question was asked, the ZMQ team developed, starting with ZeroMQ v4.0.0, the **[CurveZMQ protocol](http://curvezmq.org/)**, which is an authentication and encryption protocol for ZeroMQ based on CurveCP and NaCl - fast, secure elliptic-curve crypto. This allows encrypted ZMQ message exchange, which would supposedly be secure over the internet.

For more details see [Using ZeroMQ Security part 1](http://hintjens.com/blog:48). Some of the features that were added at the time are:

> A new wire protocol, ZMTP 3.0, that adds a security handshake to all
>   ZeroMQ connections.
>
> A new security protocol, CurveZMQ, that implements "perfect forward security" between two ZeroMQ peers over a TCP connection. I'll
>   explain CurveZMQ below.
>
> A set of security mechanisms for ZMTP: NULL, PLAIN, and CURVE, each described by their own RFCs. NULL is essentially what we had
>   before. PLAIN allows simple username and password authentication.
>   CURVE implements the CurveZMQ protocol.
>   [...]

For secure messaging over the internet, one would seek to implement, for example, the *Ironhouse pattern*. See [part 2](http://hintjens.com/blog:49#toc6) for a description.

There are certainly Ruby implementations for this protocol, but I did not look for them.

If one is looking for Python implementations, one can look at these resources:

- https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/tree/master/examples/security
- https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/se-distributed-apps-zeromq-part2/